# How to fix express httpServer CORS error for web sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, cors

I'm facing CORS issue that I have no idea how to solve, I have to use web sockets on my backend server, but for this I must implement http server and then my CORS error is coming. So before I used code like below and my request were working, I could easily handle and access every route.

```js
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

However, when I have implemented my httpServer I start to see errors like these:

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://showtime.up.railway.app/api/auth/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).**

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://showtime.up.railway.app/api/auth/register. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 503.**

```js
// imports
import authRoutes from "infrastructure/routes/authRoutes";
import scoreRoutes from "infrastructure/routes/scoreRoutes";
import userRoutes from "infrastructure/routes/userRoutes";
import roomRoutes from "infrastructure/routes/roomRoutes";
import adminRoutes from "infrastructure/routes/adminRoutes";

// Sockets
import { Server as SocketIOServer } from "socket.io";
import { setupSocketController } from "@presentation/sockets/socketController";

// Path
import path from "path";

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
export const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, "uploads");

const app = express();
const port = 4321;

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    Headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",

    origin: ["https://showtime.up.railway.app", "http://localhost:4321"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

setupSocketController(io);

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/score", scoreRoutes);
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/rooms", roomRoutes);
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoutes);

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm using railway server, so may be error is hiding there, but I don't know. I would appreciate any help, since I'm trying to resolve this issue about 7 hours straight